# how can I limit input to 5 lines in a UITextView on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a UITextView in which the user enters lines of text. After the entry of the text I take a screen capture. Problem is, if you enter more than visible lines in textView, you can't screen capture all the text. I tried disabling scrolling, but that makes it worse because text entry from keyboard makes the textview scroll into non-visible area and there's no way for the user to scroll text down again. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is also a ScrollView, so you can use it's contentSize property to only allow text input if the text fits the textView like this:

```
-(BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // Only allow text input if the size of the content is smaller than the size of the textView
    return (textView.contentSize.height < textView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

You will also need to disable the scrolling like you did, to make the UI look good.

Comment: Thank you. But this is still a problem. With this code you can enter a return which goes out of the visible area, which then locks you out of doing editing in the textView. Any further thoughts?